# Can I combine multiple domains under one Google Apps account?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, account-management

I have one domain for which I use Google Apps (Standard Edition) to provide email. I've recently started another website at another domain, and I want to use Google Apps (again, Standard Edition) also to provide the email for this new domain.

Do I need to go through the entire registration process again and create a whole new Google Apps account for the new domain, or can/should I add it on to my existing services?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer: Yes.**

However, there are some things I think I should say about that approach.

For completely unrelated sites, it's probably best to sign up for completely unrelated Google Apps accounts. Domain aliases will work, but all sites will share the same limitations on how many users can be created (quotas). Separate accounts will each have their own independent quotas.

If you alias, you'll have 50 free users to divide among all the domains. If you create separate accounts, you'll have 50 free users per domain.

Hope that helps you. Personally, I'd create a new account.

Comment: +1 good points. Personally I wound up going with a domain alias because it's simpler, and since these are personal websites I'm really the only one who needs an email account (and I'm nowhere near hitting my quota), but I imagine most people would not be in my situation.

Answer (score 1):

I have Google Apps Standard Edition, and the option for [adding a domain alias](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=53295) is enabled for me. I think it's exactly what you want to do:

> Associate another domain with this
>   account to let your users share the
>   same mailbox with multiple email
>   addresses

Comment: Well, what I had in mind was getting a new set of mailboxes for the new domain (since they're completely separate, unrelated sites). But I guess aliasing would work too. +1 for now.